# implement a text classifier with python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

i try to implement a Persian text classifier with python, i use excel to read my data and make my data set.
i would be thankful if you have any suggestion about better implementing.

i tried this code to access to body of messages which have my conditions and store them. i took screenshot of my excel file to help more.
for example i want to store body of messages which its col "foolish" (i mean F column) have value of 1(true).
https://ibb.co/DzS1RpY "screenshot"

```
import pandas as pd

file='1.xlsx'

sorted=pd.read_excel(file,index_col='foolish')

var=sorted[['body']][sorted['foolish']=='1']

print(var.head())
```

expected result is body of rows 2,4,6,8.

Comment: Is this an excel problem? If not, don't tag with excel.

Comment: @solarmike excel was used in this problem.

Comment: So then sort the data correctly before exporting it.

Comment: @anky_91 i tried but faced to error can't assign to operator.

Comment: @anky_91 `df-data=df[['body']][df['foolish']=='1']`

Comment: @anky_91 i explain it as an answer. but its not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try assigning like this:

```
df_data=df["body"][df["foolish"]==1.0]
```

dont use `-` which is a python operator instead use `_` (underscore)

Also note that this will return a series.

For a dataframe , use:

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(df['body'][df["foolish"]==1.0])
```